# How to do server side pagination with grouping in kendo grid angular?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to implement server side pagination with grouping in kendo grid angular. For server side pagination we need to give total count for kendo grid.

```
data:GridDataResult;
this.data= {
data: this.responseData,
total: 40
}
```

But for kendo grid gruoping we need give data which is processed like this

```
data: any;
state: State = {
        skip: 0,
        take: 5,
        group: [{ field: 'employeeName' }]
    };
data = process(this.responseData,this.state)
```

responseData is the data which came from server side. From server side Iam getting only 10 but we have total of 40 records. If we click page 2 the next 10 records will came from server.
data must be passed for kendo grid. This method works fine but issue producing without totalcount for pagination.
So how we can do kendo grid grouping and server side pagination.